# Create and send Google sheets range

Tags: google-sheets, report

I have a Google sheet with data on 6 columns
Column A is date (dd-mm-yyyy) and main filter for results

My question is,
Is it possible to make an automated process to send an attached pdf on the first of the month with the data from the previous month?

Thank you

I tried the following from ChatGPT

```
function createMonthlyPDFAndEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace 'Sheet1' with the name of your sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:C' + lastRow); // Replace 'A1:C' with the range you want to include in the PDF
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  // Get the current month and year
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  
  // Calculate the previous month and year
  var previousMonth = currentMonth === 0 ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
  var previousYear = currentMonth === 0 ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
  
  // Filter the data to include only the previous month's data
  var previousMonthData = data.filter(function(row) {
    var date = new Date(row[0]);
    return date.getMonth() === previousMonth && date.getFullYear() === previousYear;
  });
  
  // Create a new sheet with the filtered data
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Monthly Report - ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'MMMM') + ' ' + currentYear);
  var newRange = newSheet.getRange(1, 1, previousMonthData.length, data[0].length);
  newRange.setValues(previousMonthData);
  
  // Convert the new sheet to a PDF and delete the sheet
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheet.getId());
  var blob = newFile.getAs('application/pdf').setName(newSheet.getName() + '.pdf');
  newFile.setTrashed(true);
  
  // Get the email address to send the PDF to
  var recipient = 'recipient@example.com'; // Replace with the email address you want to send the PDF to
  
  // Send an email with the PDF attachment
  var subject = 'Monthly Report - ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'MMMM') + ' ' + currentYear;
  var body = 'Please find attached the monthly report for ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'MMMM') + ' ' + currentYear + '.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments: [blob]});
}
```